# How to validate several file buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

The below code denotes 
if we click send button with out select the files and 
didn't enter the staff name,the alert message will be displayed 
alert message like "Fill all fields". 
But i don't know how to validate
if the files are selected.
 Please help me...

```
    <form method="post" action="Save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1"  placeholder="Staff Name" />
    <?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) { ?>
         <input type="file" name="f[]" id="f[]" />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" class="btnsend" id="btnsend" name="btnsend" value="Send"  >
```

Comment: You can do it by client side validation using Javascript or jQuery and also by Server side validation using PHP code.

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: try this kind of validation.

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

Comment: by the way do not use the same id multiple times! `id="f[]"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputFile = document.getElementById("myFile"); // a <input type="file" element
if (inputFile.files.length > 0) // check if files are selected
```

do this for each input

... You could check if all files are selected like this:

```
var inputFiles = document.getElementsByName("f[]"); // a <input type="file" element
var allSelected = true
for(var i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; ++i) {
     if (inputFile.files.length == 0) {
         allSelected = false
         break
     }
 }
 if(allSelected) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: We can use name too... Where did you find the `id` attribute ?

Comment: @RayonDabre well thats just an example, he can select the element in the way he prefers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer is worked for single file button. But i have create several file button using for loop at run time(file button id is f[]). Here how to get the id?.

Comment: @Senthilkumar you can do the same with a loop, you don't need the Id

Comment: @Senthilkumar I added an example

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnsend").click(function(){
$flag = false;
$sid = $("#txt1").val();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
$f = $_FILES["f"]["name"][$i];
if($sid=="" && $f=="")
{
$flag = true;
break;
}
}
if($flag==true)
{
alert("Fill all fields");
return false;
}
});
});
</script>        IS it correct?

Comment: @Senthilkumar no. `$_FILES` does not exist in JavaScript. Did you see my Example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the elements having name as `f[]`

> `querySelectorAll()` Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

As you are using `input type="submit"`, you need to prevent default behaviour of the submit button which is `submitting` the form. Or else `action` will be taken once user clicks that button.

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('btnsend').addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var files = document.querySelectorAll('[name="f[]"]');
  var error = '';
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, function(elem, index) {
    if (elem.value === '') {
      error += 'Invalid file ' + (index + 1) + '\n';
    }
  });
  if (error) {
    alert(error);
  } else {
    alert('All files are selected!');
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="Save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" placeholder="Staff Name" />
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="f[]" id="f[]" />
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="f[]" id="f[]" />
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="f[]" id="f[]" />
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="f[]" id="f[]" />
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="f[]" id="f[]" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="btnsend" id="btnsend" name="btnsend" value="Send">
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/epxgomg8/)